# How can I load image url to google map marker icon in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, google-maps, android-jetpack-compose, marker

I get the image URL from the server and I want to load the URL in the Google Maps marker icon. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

using Glide Library

```
fun loadIcon(
    context: Context,
    url: String?,
    placeHolder: Int,
): BitmapDescriptor? {
    try {
        var bitmap: Bitmap? = null
        Glide.with(context)
            .asBitmap()
            .load(url)
            .error(placeHolder)
            // to show a default icon in case of any errors
            .into(object : CustomTarget<Bitmap>() {
                override fun onResourceReady(
                    resource: Bitmap,
                    transition: Transition<in Bitmap>?
                ) {

                    bitmap = resource

                }

                override fun onLoadCleared(placeholder: Drawable?) {

                }
            })
        return BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap!!)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        return null
    }

}
```

then call

```
 var bitmap = loadIcon(context, item.icon, R.drawable.placeholder_image,)
                    Marker(
                        state = MarkerState(
                            position = LatLng(
                                item.lat.toDouble(),
                                item.long.toDouble()
                            )
                        ),
                        title = item.name,
                        icon = bitmap,
                        )
```

Answer (score 0):

I have written an article to show custom marker on google map:

https://towardsdev.com/jetpack-compose-custom-google-map-marker-erselan-khan-e6e04178a30b

You have to get the drawable object from your image url, which you can easily get by using the coil library for image loading.

https://towardsdev.com/image-url-to-bitmap-using-coil-erselan-khan-6f190ce83d7f